# Convert abbreviated month name to number within single line

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi all I am very new to mysql statement I just wondering how do we convert and get only Abbreviated month name to number with single code Example String "2008Jan20" to 2008-01-20 Then get only month 01

```
 MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(6, '%m'));
```

Comment: Can we ask why you would want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `str_to_date` converts the string into a date value based on the format string

```
str_to_date('2008Jan20','%Y%b%d')
```

Get month number

```
 Month(str_to_date('2008Jan20','%Y%b%d')) //get month number
```

Get `MONTHNAME`

```
MONTHNAME(str_to_date('2008Jan20','%Y%b%d')) //get month name
```

Comment: cannot use str_to_date Function